# Is $x\times(T\cdot n)$ a triple product?

Tags: analytic-geometry, tensors

Is $x\times(T\cdot n)$ a triple product?

That is, does $x\times(T\cdot n) = - n \cdot (T\times x)$ ?

Where $T$ is a matriz (2-rank tensor).

I try the Einstein notation, but got stuck:

$
\epsilon_{ijk}x_jT_{kl}n_l = -\epsilon_{ikj}n_lT_{kl}x_j=-n_l\epsilon_{ikj}T_{kl}x_j
$

$
?= -n_l(T_l \times x)_i \; \dots \; ?
$

Comment: What kind of object is $x$? a $3$-vector? What about $n$? Is $T$ a $3\times3$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, x and n are 3-vectors, T a matrix. This strange calculation is in Jackson’s Classical Electrodynamics, and without explanation, so this is my attempt to understand.

Comment: Then I don't understand $T\cdot n$ and $T\times x$. If it's just a matrix times a vector, shouldn't they just be $Tn$ and $Tx$? And won't $x\times(Tn)$ be a vector, while $-n\cdot(Tx)$ will be a scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we for some strange reason define the "cross product" of a Matrix $T^u_j$ and a vector $n_k$ like this (and please note that this is by no means a vector, rather a (2,0) tensor)
$$(T\times n)^{iu}=\varepsilon^{ijk}T^u_jn_k$$
a natural analogy of the usual triple product is (and again please note that this is not a scalar, rather a contravariant vector)
$$\left(x\cdot(T\times n)\right)^u=x_i\epsilon^{ijk}T^u_jn_k$$
Now we can use the skew symmetric property $\varepsilon^{ijk}=-\varepsilon^{kji}$ and a simple renaming (swap $i,k$) to get
$$x_i\epsilon^{ijk}T^u_jn_k=n_k\epsilon^{ijk}T^u_jx_i=-n_k\epsilon^{kji}T^u_jx_i=-n_i\epsilon^{ijk}T^u_jx_k=\left(-n\cdot(T\times x)\right)^u$$
Hence
$$x\cdot(T\times n)=-n\cdot(T\times x)$$